# Count each occurrence of an element with a certain attribute value in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this XML file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="bg2.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>

<root text="Récapitulatif des bugs MD 360">
<graph>
<item text="3988 (K2) : [MozillaMD]" severite="K2" importance="Anomalie" status="RESOLVED" etat=" WORKSFORME" date="2016-11-15"></item>
<item text="4853 (K2) : Profil Midas" severite="K2" importance="Evolution" status="ASSIGNED" etat=" FIXED" date="2016-11-15"></item>
<item text="4991 (K3) : ECU " severite="K3" importance="Evolution" status="RESOLVED" etat=" FIXED" date="2016-11-15"></item>
</graph>
</root>
```

I want to count how much `severite="K2"` I have. For that I'm doing that in XSLT but I always have 0 :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="graph">
 K2 -- <xsl:value-of select="count(graph/item[severite='K2'])"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Change**

```
K2 -- <xsl:value-of select="count(graph/item[severite='K2'])"/>
```

**to**

```
K2 -- <xsl:value-of select="count(item[@severite='K2'])"/>
```

**because**

1. The current node is already `graph`, so your XPath shouldn't repeat `graph`.
2. `severite` is an attribute, not an element, so should be prefixed with `@`.

Answer (score 1):

> count(graph/item[severite='K2'])

Counts all `item` with parent `graph`. `item` is filtered: child `severite` must have the content 'K2'.

**Solution**

`count(item[@severite='K2'])`

- `severite` is an attribute of element `item`. `@` is needed.
- As well: Your current context-node is already `graph`.